# Visual Studio 2012 Update query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use this `Update` command but it isn't working properly. It is working when I run it in SQL Server 2008 but not in Visual Studio 2012

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("UPDATE dwh_staging_table SET pestpopulation1 = @avg_pest1 WHERE DistrictName = @DistrictName and TownName = @TownName And VarietyOfCrop = @V_Crop And pestpopulation1 = @pest", con1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avg_pest1",16);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DistrictName", "Multan");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TownName","Ambala");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@V_Crop","NIAB 999");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pest",0);

adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
```

Comment: it is not producing any error its just not updatng values where the petpopulation is zero  when i run the same query in ms sql server 2008 it works..

Comment: you are assigning update command to select command of adapter check my answer , and also use the parameterised queries to avoid the sql injection attacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `Sql Update Command` to `SelectCommand` of `SqlDataAdapter`.

Try this:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("your update command");
```

Note: your update command is open to `SQL injection attacks`.
Use `PARAMETERISED QUERIES` to avoid them.

**Example of PARAMETERISED QUERIES :**

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("update products set price=@price where id=@id");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price",1234);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",12);

adapter.UpdateCommand=cmd;
```

**Complete Solution:** (using PARAMETERISED QUERIES)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dwh_staging_table SET pestpopulation1=@pestpopulation1 WHERE DistrictName=@DistrictName and TownName=@TownName And VarietyOfCrop=@VarietyOfCrop And pestpopulation1=@pestpopulation11", con1);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pestpopulation1", row[3]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DistrictName", row[0].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TownName", row[1].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VarietyOfCrop", row[2].ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pestpopulation11", 0);

adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
```

Comment: @user1056466: check my edited answer with section `Complete Solution`

Comment: @user1056466: call .ToString() on DistrictName,Townname,VarietyOfCrop command parameters as shown in my answer, check my edited version.

Comment: @user1056466: did you try calling .ToString()

Comment: @user1056466: are you calling Update() function on adapter object?

Comment: i edited the question.. see even i hardcoded the values its not working

Comment: @user1056466: are you executing the Update() function on adapter object?

Comment: yes by this u mean adapter.udpateCommand=cmd i did it see the edited version of my question..plz help

Comment: i wasnot using cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); thanks

Comment: @user1056466: are you able to run the query now?